# How to perform database tracking for a portal that is build with codeigniter framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Need to perform database [DB] tracking for my portal that is build with CodeIgniter framework.

Since my portal is build with codeigniter framework , all db queries [`insert, update, delete, select`] will be performed with Query builder class.

```
$this->db->insert('mytable', $object);
$this->db->update('mytable');
...
```

For DB tracking, I have created a table named `dblogs`, where all the queries corresponding to each action [`insert, update, select, ...`] that a user performs in the portal will be inserted along with the user session id.

**`dblogs` table structure**, I prefer:

```
TransactionID
UserID [user session id]
ProjectID
Action [insert, update, ...]
Module [in which module the action is performed like login, email, ...]
Query [complete query]
Query Status [whether the query executed successfully or not]
DateTime
IPAddress
MVC [model - controller - view file names where the action is performed]
```

**system/database/DB_query_builder.php**

```
public function insert($table = '', $set = NULL, $escape = NULL)
{
    if ($set !== NULL)
    {
        $this->set($set, '', $escape);
    }

    if ($this->_validate_insert($table) === FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $sql = $this->_insert(
        $this->protect_identifiers(
            $this->qb_from[0], TRUE, $escape, FALSE
        ),
        array_keys($this->qb_set),
        array_values($this->qb_set)
    );

    $this->_reset_write();
    $ins = $this->query($sql);
    //INSERT INTO DBLOGS 
    $this->query("INSERT INTO `dblogs` (`user_id`,`proj_id`,`action`,`query`,`query_status`,`date_time`,`ipaddress`,`mvc`) 
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '2019-05-08 00:00:00', '1','test')");

    return $ins;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: In the insert query for dblogs , how can I get the value for 'user_id' which is stored in the session variable : $this->session->set_userdata("user_id", $row->user_id);

Comment: Have you read the [CodeIgniter session documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data)?